# Cross class declaration error?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am trying to do mapping with Restkit and created 2 classes as below. I got the following errors:

- **Unknown type name "Card"** in **Campaign.h**
- **Unknown type name "Campaign"** in **Card.h**
- **Property with 'retain (or strong)' attribute must be of object type**
- ... more but similar errors

My question is there a way to achieve below class declaration by re-using class.

**Campaign.h**

```
#import "Card.h"

@interface Campaign : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber* campaignId;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* title;
@property (nonatomic, strong) Card* card;

@end
```

**Card.h**

```
#import "Campaign.h"

@interface Card : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber* cardId;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) Campaign* campaign;

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case someone need it in future. Here my solution:

**Campaign.h**

```
@class Card;

@interface Campaign : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber* campaignId;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* title;
@property (nonatomic, strong) Card* card;

@end
```

**Campaign.m**

```
#import "Card.h"

@implementation Campaign

...

@end
```

**Card.h**

```
@class Campaign;

@interface Card : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber* cardId;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) Campaign* campaign;

@end
```

**Card.m**

```
#import "Campaign.h"

@implementation Card

...

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

Usually, in headers, you use forward class declarations, in order to avoid imports conflicts. So in `Campaign.h`, before your interface, you'd have `@class Card`, and in `Card.h`, you'd have `@class Campaign`. This merely tells the compiler that these class exists & are defined somewhere else; that's usually all you need to know in a header.

Comment: I did try to use forward class. However I received the other error of " Property 'name' cannot be found in foward class object."

Comment: Oops... I think I know the problem. I didn't include all the required headers. That's why I am getting property cannot be found error. Cheers!